# ValidationError: Post validation failed: title: Path `title` is required. in nodejs api

Tags: node.js, multer

I am making a restful API using nodejs. Here I have added multer for file upload before implementing multer it was working fine but now whenever I try to create post using `postman` i get error somthing like this.

> error

```
{ ValidationError: Post validation failed: title: Path `title` is required.
    at ValidationError.inspect (C:\projects\adi-site\api\node_modules\mongoose\l
ib\error\validation.js:59:24)
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:490:31)
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:191:10)
    at Object.formatWithOptions (util.js:84:12)
    at Console.(anonymous function) (console.js:188:15)
    at Console.log (console.js:199:31)
    at post.save.then.catch.err (C:\projects\adi-site\api\src\routes\posts.js:70
:17)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  errors:
   { title:
      { ValidatorError: Path `title` is required.
          at new ValidatorError (C:\projects\adi-site\api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validator.js:29:11)
          at validate (C:\projects\adi-site\api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:975:13)
          at C:\projects\adi-site\api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1028:11
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
          at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (C:\projects\adi-site\api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:984:19)
          at C:\projects\adi-site\api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2098:9
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

> and when i try to `log` req.body i get this

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  'title ': 'this is title with imahih',  <-----//i think here `key` title is in the wrong format I have no idea where it is coming from and how to fix this.
  overview: 'this is overview of the image',
  content: 'this is image content' }
```

> routes/posts.js <-- this is my code

```
router.post('/', upload.single('postImage'),(req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const post = new Post({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        title: req.body.title,
        overview: req.body.overview,
        content: req.body.content,
        postImage: req.file.path
    });
    post.save().then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(201).json({
            message: "Post created",
            createdPost: {
                _id: result._id,
                title: result.title,
                overview: result.overview,
                content: result.content,
                postImage: result.postImage
            }
        })
    }).catch(err => {   
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        })
    })
})
```

> this is how i am sending request

[image: error-image]

Comment: Are you using `bodyparser` before adding the router? Also you might want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38075763/message-path-is-required

Comment: @eol yes i am using body-parser.

Comment: @eol i visited this link but this doesn't solve my problem as i am uploading image too so i need to go with `form-data`

Comment: Are you sure there's no trailing space for the title in the form data request in postman? Maybe do an export as curl just to be sure.

Comment: @eol yeah i am sure there is no trailing space for the title.

Answer (score 0):

> Post validation failed: title: Path `title` is required.

You're getting this error because there is a space after the `title` in postman form.

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  'title ': 'this is title with imahih',  // You can notice title being wrapped in '' with extra space
  overview: 'this is overview of the image',
  content: 'this is image content' }
```

You can either trim the extra space in postman or handle the case at the server side for that.

```
'use strict';

router.post('/', upload.single('postImage'), (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const formData = Object.keys(req.body).reduce((cleanFormData, attribute) => {
    const key = attribute.trim();
    cleanFormData [key] = req.body[attribute];
    return cleanFormData;
  }, {});

  console.log(formData);
  console.log(formData.title); // logs 'this is title with imahih'
  .....
});
```